# Diabolic Substance

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, word-problem, rebus

What is it :

> Colloquially, it is a **Diabolic** way to win at athletic events.
>
> Take **a single one**, and it might be shaped like a star.

Comment: Is it doping? 
Btw, this looks a nice puzzle if rebus, lateral-thinking and riddle are all involved!

Comment: Note that the prefix "di-" means two, twice, or double. That contrasts nicely with "a single one" and so I believe that's a piece of the word-play.

Comment: Building on Engineer's idea, remove "di" from "Diabolic" and you get "abolic." Anabolic could refer to anabolic steroids.

Comment: This comment thread was going in the the Right Direction. **Mark Bannister** has got the answer , though I am not sure if whether he saw these comments or not. Over-All , great inputs from **leoll2** , **Engineer Toast** , **Aggie Kidd** ! ! ! !

Comment: I will be adding the exact expected answer to all my puzzles, so that the clues are explained, but if somebody else has got the correct answer, then that will be the "Accepted Answer".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Anabolic steroid(s)

If you have two, they are

> Di-abolic steroids

If you have one, it is

> A steroid - ie. Asteroid, meaning starlike.

Comment: Excellent ! ! ! !

Comment: @Prem: Excellent question!!

Comment: No, I can't believe it, I thought of Anabolic Steroids but I missed the Ana- Di- thing and completely abandoned my idea! Anyway, good job!

Comment: Ah! I never considered asteroid. Clever girl.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the answer :

> Diabolic way implies cheating and news reports always mention sports people caught taking anabolic steroids. It is usually, or "Colloquially", reported as simply "steriods".

Completing the answer :

> Now take a single steriod, or "a steriod" to get "asteriod", which is shaped like a star !!!!